# How to obtain auto-generated id for clicked documents

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore

I use vue and firestore.

I generated the document in the collection through the code below.

```
<template>
  <input type="text" v-model="form.title">
</template>

methods: {
  async saveform () {
    await db.collection('forms').add(
      {
        title: this.title
      }
    )
  }
}
```

And I read it through the code below.

```
<div v-for="(form, i) in forms" :key="form.id">
  {{form.title}}
<button @click="readid">readid</button>
<button @click="deleteform">delete</button>
</div>

async created () {
  const sn = await db.collection('forms').get()
  sn.forEach(doc => {
    const { title } = doc.data()
    this.forms.push({
      title
    })
  })
```

[image: firestore img]

I want to get the ID of the form clicked by clicking the readit button in the code above.

Because to use db.collection('forms').doc().delete()

This is because I need to know the ID of the clicked form to put id in the doc().

Please help me. The Firestore official document is not enough to deal with auto-generated id.

Please comment if there is not enough explanation. I am willing to edit.
I'm not going to sleep until I figure this out, so I can always edit it.

-edited-
I'm sorry I didn't explain it correctly. I don't just know the id. I want to create a code that deletes the form when I click the delete button in the form.

I think I'll change the question and post it again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the `id` of a created document you can use this kind of code:

```js
const formSnap=await db.collection('forms').add(
      {
        title: this.title
      }
    )

//your id
console.log('id',formSnap.id)
```

If you want to get the `id` before you add any data you can do it like this:

```js
const ref = db.collection("forms").doc();
console.log('id',ref .id)
```

If you neeed it in the loop:

```js
async created () {
  const sn = await db.collection('forms').get()
  sn.forEach(doc => {
    const { title } = doc.data()
    console.log('id',doc.id) // here is it in the loop
    this.forms.push({
      title
    })
  })
```

To delete the form data by clicking on a button you first need to store the `formID` value somewhere and use it later to delete the form data:

```js
methods: {
  async saveform () {
    const formSnap=await db.collection('forms').add(
      {
        title: this.title
      }
    )

  return formSnap.id
  },
async deleteform(fID) {
   await db.collection('forms').doc(fID).delete()
  }
}
```

And call it like this:

```js
await deleteform(formID)
```

Comment: Sorry I didn't understand.
I don't know my auto-generated id

Comment: I want to get the ID of the document that has already been created.

Comment: That is then the first code snippet in the answer. Did you try it out?

Comment: Or do you need the id in the `forEach` loop?

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't explain it correctly. I don't just know the id.
I want to create a code that deletes the form when I click the delete button in the form.

Comment: I have updated the answer. Check out the last part. It shows how to delete the form by using the id we saved before when creating the data.

Comment: How am I supposed to declare formID outside the methods()?

Comment: You can declare where ever you want and use it as parameter to the function `deleteform`.

Comment: I have change the answer in a ways that the creation method returns the formID and the deletion one takes a formID as parameter.

Comment: Finally I understand it and it works well.
I don't know how to express my gratitude.
Thank you for taking the time to me.

Comment: Thx. Happy to help . I'm glad it worked out :)

Answer (score 0):

In my app I can use this code:

```
let response = await firestore.collection("db").doc(dbId).get();
this.file = response.data();
console.log("doc id", response.id);
```

so I assume this should work:

```
const sn = await db.collection('forms').get();

sn.forEach(doc => {
    const { title } = doc.data()
    const id = doc.id // <-- This is it
    
    this.forms.push({
        title
    });
})
```

Okay, if you want to delete the doc if the "deleteform" function is called, then this should work:

```
// Your Template
<div v-for="(form, i) in forms" :key="form.id">
    {{form.title}}
    <button @click="readid">readid</button>
    <button @click="deleteform(form.id)">delete</button>
</div>

// Your created hook
async created () {
    const sn = await db.collection('forms').get();

    sn.forEach(doc => {
        const { title } = doc.data()
        const id = doc.id // <-- This is it
    
        this.forms.push({
            title,
            id,
        });
    })
}

// And your function for deleting the document
async deleteform(docId) {
    await db.collection('forms').doc(docId).delete()
}
```

Hope I could help you!

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But it seems to be different.

Comment: I have not tried this because I have tried another answer, but I am trying now. Thank you for making time for me, too.